# HTML Parser iOS

Tags: ios, html, парсер, iphone

Добрый день. Мне нужно **распарсить HTML страницу**. Ничего не обычного, но вот беда. Немогу дать ладу пармерам, может кто-то подскажет **какий парсер** самый **дружелюбный для новичка iOS**.

Буду благодарен каким-то уникальным урокам, ихмо в Google я уже все обшарил.

Comment: Какую цель преследуете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос старый, но может кому будет еще актуально. Попробуйте вот это решение:

Objective-C-HMTL-Parser